# ML .Net Can’t extract trained model parameters

Tags: c#, ml.net

Using the code from the microsoft website I am trying to retrain a model.

```
            // Extract trained model parameters
            var originalModelParameters =
                ((ISingleFeaturePredictionTransformer<object>)trainedModel).Model as PoissonRegressionModelParameters;
```

However this gives me the error

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.ML.Data.TransformerChain`1[Microsoft.ML.ITransformer]' to type 'Microsoft.ML.ISingleFeaturePredictionTransformer`1[System.Object]'.'
```

This is how I saved the dataprep and model

```
var csvmodel = csvpipeline.Fit(csvTrainingDataView);



            // Define data preparation estimator
            IEstimator<ITransformer> dataPrepEstimator =
                mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", new string[] { "t" })
                    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.NormalizeMinMax("Features"));

            // Create data preparation transformer
            ITransformer dataPrepTransformer = dataPrepEstimator.Fit(csvTrainingDataView);

            // Define StochasticDualCoordinateAscent regression algorithm estimator
            var Estimator = mlContext.Regression.Trainers.LbfgsPoissonRegression();

            // Pre-process data using data prep operations
            IDataView transformedData = dataPrepTransformer.Transform(csvTrainingDataView);



            //savemodel
            //csv savemodel
            savemodel(csvmlContext, csvmodel, transformedData);
            /*
            var modelPath = string.Format("{0}/MODEL/{1}-{2}.zip", Environment.CurrentDirectory,"Model","Testing");
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(modelPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
                csvmlContext.Model.Save(csvmodel, csvTrainingDataView.Schema, fileStream);*/



            // Save Data Prep transformer
            savedatprep(csvmlContext, dataPrepTransformer, csvTrainingDataView);
```

using my method

```
static void savemodel(MLContext mlcontext,ITransformer model,IDataView Data)
        {
            var modelPath = string.Format("{0}/MODEL/{1}-{2}.zip", Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Model", "Testing");
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(modelPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
                mlcontext.Model.Save(model, Data.Schema, fileStream);
        }
        static void savedatprep(MLContext mlcontext, ITransformer model, IDataView Data)
        {
            var modelDataPrepPath = string.Format("{0}/MODEL/{1}-{2}.zip", Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Model", "Testing_DataPrep");
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(modelDataPrepPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
                mlcontext.Model.Save(model, Data.Schema, fileStream);
        }
```

this is the structure of my data file, header and first line

```
 t,o,h,l,c,s,z,q,n,v,x,y,Ema,Rsi,Macd,MacdSign,MacdHistN3,MacdHistN2,MacdHistN1,MacdHistN0,FuturePrice
16636653,1.283,1.283,1.271,1.278,133642.8,1663666199999,170622.876,751,67266.6,85853.53,0,0,45.80812565453984,69.7112186336032,69.38782605382958,3.3440424757016984,2.8439819612832054,1.640807326496386,0.3233925797736106,0
```

I feel like I have truly tried everything and literally any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Looked at other similar questions but none of them solve it. Ive tried to change the saving process but nothing results in a different error, and Ive made sure that the parameter type is the same as the saved model.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I've missed anything but I don't see you calling fit to train the model. I see you called `Fit` using the preprocessing pipeline and some other `csvpipeline` not mentioned here but all that does is apply the preprocessing transforms to your dataset.

You might want to try:

```cs
var model = Estimator.Fit(transformedData)
```

This will result in a trained model where you should be able to extract model parameters from.

Also, since I believe `Estimator` is a type in ML.NET, consider renaming it to something else. Even lowercase might be enough.